# How to use osmfilter to drop features with non-empty values on a key?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmfilter

I know one can use `--drop="key=value"` option with `osmfilter` to filter out OSM features for which `key` has a value of `value`.

For example, I can use

```
osmfilter input.o5m --drop="service=parking_aisle" --drop="service=driveway"  -o=output.o5m
```

to drop out service roads with the service tag and `parking_aisle` or `driveway` values.

How can drop all features for which the `service` have a non-empty value?

I tried `--drop="service="`, and it seems to drop features with an empty `service` tag too.

Any official documentation on how to do this?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you could try [osmium-tool](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/) instead. It is faster than osmfilter and has a less-weird syntax.